# Submitted array param that is permitted in strong params disappears

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having trouble with strong params in a Rails 5.0.2 api. I can't post the exact code, but the params gathered in a method and then used in the create action in the controller.

```
def create
     render_json Model.create(create_params_method)
end

def create_params_method
     create_params = params.require(:model).permit(:name, array_of_ids: [])
     create_params
end
```

When I submit the request, `params` contains the `array_of_params` parameter, but when it runs through the params method, it disappears and I just have the name. Trying to track down where/why `array_of_ids` is getting rejected, but no luck so far. I use stack all the time for help and I can provide more information if needed, but this is my first time actually asking a question so bear with me .

Comment: Paste the params you see in the rails console to see if we can find something there. Also, isn't the `create_params_method` method defined more than once ?. Also, put a pry before the `render_json` part and inspect `params`, call  `create_params_method` too check what it returns, etc.

Comment: Off topic but, don't name your methods `something_method`. Also the only line you need in your `create_params` method is `params.require(:model).permit(:name, array_of_ids: [])`. Unless you need to do something else to the params just let Ruby do its magic.

Comment: You say `array_of_params` but your code says `array_of_ids`. Is this just a mistake in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Because `params.require(:model).permit(:name, array_of_ids: [])` does is filter out the `mentioned params` from `received params`, so if you have anything else it will be gone. e.g if you recieve

```
user: {id: 1, name: 'sahil', last_name: 'grover', roles: [1,2,3], is_admin: true}
```

and your params filter is

```
params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :last_name, roles: [])
```

then the resultant you will get is

```
{id: 1, name: 'sahil', last_name: 'grover', roles: [1,2,3]}
```

`is_admin` will be removed since it is not listed in `permitted params`.

Comment: This is a good observation and should be helpful to the OP but they are whitelisting (permitting) their `array_of_ids ` param.